# can't integrate AdminLTE theme with YII2 backend app

Tags: php, themes, admin, yii-extensions, yii2

I want to use the amazing AdminLTE theme withe my backend application in YII2.
I followed these steps

1-I've Downloaded adminLTE from [here](http://almsaeedstudio.com/)

2-I've extracted it to `backend\web\`

3-Changed the folder name to become adminlte

4-Changed `AppAsset.php` located in `backend\assets\` like this

```
 public $css = [
        'css/site.css',
        **'adminlte/css/AdminLTE.css', // ADDED THIS**
        ];
    public $js = [
        **'adminlte/js/AdminLTE/app.js', // ADDED THI**
        ];
```

But I still have the default yii2 theme being displayed, why ?

Comment: You can use https://github.com/dmstr/yii2-adminlte-asset also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `public $sourcePath = '@web/adminlte';` and you should use [AdminLTE index.html](https://github.com/almasaeed2010/AdminLTE/blob/master/index.html) instead your main/layout.php